# Child is deleting parent and its child also in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using country->State (OTM) -> Districts (OTM) relationship using hibernate.

The problem I am facing is when I am trying to delete single State then either

1) it is deleting all States, its parent (country) and **all** (related and unrelated) children (districts).
OR
2) It is not deleting anything

I have spent lots of time in google but not able to solve. Can someone help me please?

Below is my relationship at entity level. I tried with different cascadetype combinations at **StateMaster** entity like

1) `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`   -  Deleting country,state and all districts(related and unrelated to the state)
2) `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)` - Does not delete country,state and districts
3) `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)` - Does not delete country,state and districts
4) `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)`    -  Deleting country,state and all districts(related and unrelated to the state)
5) `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)` - Does not delete country,state and districts
6) `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)` - Does not delete country,state and districts

```
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE country_master SET delete_ind = 'Y' WHERE country_id = ?")
@Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
public class CountryMaster implements Serializable {
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to StateMaster
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="countryMaster", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
    private List<StateMaster> stateMasters;
}
```

```
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE state_master SET delete_ind = 'Y' WHERE state_id =   ?")
@Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
public class StateMaster implements Serializable {
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DistrictMaster
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="stateMaster", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
    private List<DistrictMaster> districtMasters;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to CountryMaster
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id", updatable=false)
    private CountryMaster countryMaster;
}
```

```
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE district_master SET delete_ind = 'Y' WHERE dist_id = ?")
@Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
public class DistrictMaster implements Serializable {
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Address
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="districtMaster",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to StateMaster
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="state_id")
    private StateMaster stateMaster;
}
```

```
@Transactional(value="adminTransactionManager")
public MasterDataBean deleteCountryStateDist(MasterDataBean masterDataBean, String countryCode,String stateCode,String distCode) {
    ..........
    ...........
    else if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(stateCode)) {
        StateMaster state = stateMasterRepository.findByStateCode(stateCode);
        if(state == null) {
            if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.error("State does not exists");
            }
            masterDataBean.setErrorMsg("State does not exists for state code: " + stateCode);
            return masterDataBean;
        }

        stateMasterRepository.delete(state);
    }
}
```

Please note:
I have implemented soft delete in my code. so, at the time of deletion it updates the delete_ind flag to 'Y'

Comment: The problem looks like with the `CascadeType.ALL` on `ManyToOne` relationships. Can you remove `cascade` attribute on all `ManyToOne` relationship in all the `CountyMaster, StateMaster, DistrictMaster` entities and give it a try.

Comment: You've already demonstrated the issue is with Cascade.REMOVE, what is it that you are asking? When you remove a State, if your reference to Country is Cascade REMOVE or ALL, it forces JPA to remove the State as well.  The state-> Country reference is also cascade.ALL, so all referenced states are then removed, which cascades through the object model over every reference that is marked Cascade.ALL or REMOVE.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have removed the cascade attribute from ManyToOne relationship as mentioned by Madhusudana. Now state/country/district nothing is getting deleted now. I have tried with all cascade attributes and without cascase attribute also. I am not getting expected result. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Issue fixed....As per [this link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Cascading_Remove_) CascadeType.REMOVE and CascadeType.ALL should have same result. But in practice CascadeType.REMOVE has solved my problem. I have used CascadeType.REMOVE in OneToMany and I didn't use any cascadetype in manytoone relation as mentioned by Madhusudana